# Same ID different Class using "this"

Tags: jquery

I have two sets of items, one that I have my jQuery treating the class as a clickable item and  grabbing the id, it the performs a task upon the other set of corresponding items that has a different class but the same id.
Right now I've got it alerting me of the id like so:

```
$(".class1").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Can I do the following to have it change the height of the correspond item:

```
$(".class1").click(function(){
    $(".class2".this.id).animate({width:"400px", opacity:1}, 400 );
});
```

Edit (15:08 EST)

I actually have two separate DIVs acting on one another. I didn't know about the ID uniqueness rule, can I do the same thing by using a subclass in the second DIV like so?

```
<div class="class1">Click Me!</div>
<div class="class2 class1">Stuff happens here</div>

$(".class1").click(function(){
    $(".class2 "+this.class).animate({width:"400px", opacity:1}, 400 );
});
```

Comment: *"...has a different class but the same id"* that's a disturbing statement. also concatenation is `+` in js and not `.`

Comment: The `id` ***must be unique within the document:*** [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Comment: Your second code example has some funky syntax. `".class2".this.id`?

Comment: I'd recommend *same class, different ids* instead.

Comment: It's not valid to have the same ID on 2 or more elements. IDs are unique, while class names are not. Use IDs to identify your items as clickable, an class names to match a corresponding item.

Comment: `".class2".this.id` looks like PHP. In JavaScript you connect strings with the `+` operator, instead of `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have a syntax error in your code. Here is it fixed:

```
$(".class1").click(function(){
    $(".class2 #" + this.id).animate({width:"400px", opacity:1}, 400 );
});
```

Technically speaking though, it's redundant (and slower!) to specify the ID inside the context of a class since IDs are (supposed to be) unique.

```
$(".class1").click(function(){
    $("#" + this.id).animate({width:"400px", opacity:1}, 400 );
});
```

In fact, you can even just get the jQuery object from a DOM object like so:

```
$(".class1").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({width:"400px", opacity:1}, 400 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids of element must always be unique on the page. In your case since the class name is differenct you can just use the class name and find the element. Try this

```
$(".class1").click(function(){
    $(".class2").animate({width:"400px", opacity:1}, 400 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the same id to two different elements are you?

If so, you shouldn't.

If not, then why not just do `$(this).animate({width:"400px", opacity:1}, 400 );`